# How can I make part of a Joomla template editable via the CMS interface?

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla

Title says most of it.

I have inherited a Joomla site and the client wants part of the main template (a feature-type box) to be editable via the Joomla backend.

I guess really it is a content item that never gets displayed as its own page, but as a part of all pages.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

EDIT: By editable, I mean as a piece of content, not as editing the template HTML. I hardly expect non-tech users to get things right in a WYSIWYG text editor, much less change HTML code that could screw up the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the content items module.

[Content Items Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/component/option,com_mtree/task,viewlink/link_id,498/Itemid,35/)

This way a user can add content as normal using the standard content pages, but you as the developer can set the module up to show that content as a module only. You have a LOT of choices with the above module too, you can set individual, category, intro, main all that kind of thing. Dont link to the page or category and it wont be shown on the main site, just in the module :)

The joomla extension directory is full of great things.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The Custom HTML Module allows you to create, edit, and display your own free-form HTML on a Joomla site using a WYSIWYG editor.

In your administration control panel you can find the "Module Manager" under "Extensions" in the drop down navigation menu. There you can create this module, choose a position in your template to display it, and then select what sections of your site the module should be displayed on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special component for Joomla to edit templates, any part of template, any Tag. See [dewem template editor component](http://dewem.com/en/joomla.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla templates are always editable via the backend.  Just got to Extensions->Template Manager->Select the template you're using to edit it->and then up in the toolbar there will options for editing the html or the css as well as many design (look) options over on the right.  That is in Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Do you really trust clients to go in and edit the HTML that is the framework for the whole site?